# Uploading images into separate directories for every new content

Tags: media, files

My page, created using Drupal 7, will contain multiple galleries. I created new "Content Type" - "gallery" with an unlimited numer of "Image" fields. For each content of this type I want all of its images to be placed under different directory, eg. sites/default/files/gallery_01, sites/default/files/gallery_02, etc.

There is a "File directory" setting but I don't know how to make it content-dependent (when I create new content I want all uploaded images to be placed in a different directory).

Is there any way I can accomplish this ?

Comment: If this is not a hard-and-fast requirement, it will probably be much easier to just let Drupal automatically handle the storage for you.  If you will be using Drupal to display all the images anyway, you won't need to worry about where the files are actually stored; Drupal will abstract that away from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you would want to do that, I don't know. However, you can use [Filefield Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module with tokens. If you use the timestamp token you can have each directory created named based on timestamp. That will make them unique.